# Visual Studio: Updating 2 tables using a grid view

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, gridview, dropdown

I want to have a gridview which contains `Members.firstName`, `Members.LastName`, `Team.TeamName`. `Team.TeamName` should be a dropdown containing the possible TeamName's.

My Tables:

```
Members 
--------
MemberID BIGINT
FirstName NVARCHAR(50)
LastName NVARCHAR(50)
TeamID BIGINT

Team
---------
TeamID BIGINT 
TeamName NVARCHAR(50)
```

My Select:

```
SELECT Members.FirstName, Members.LastName, Team.TeamName
FROM Members 
INNER JOIN Team ON Members.TeamId = Team.TeamId
```

My Update:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateTeamMembers
(
   @TeamId BIGINT,
   @FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
   @LastName NVARCHAR(50),
   @TeamName NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Members SET FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName WHERE TeamId=@TeamId
UPDATE Team SET TeamName=@TeamName WHERE TeamId=@TeamId
END
RETURN
```

I believe the error to be with the update procedure, I get this error:

> Procedure or function updateTeamMembers has too many arguments specified.

My HTML5:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Members] WHERE [MemberId] = @original_MemberId AND (([FirstName] = @original_FirstName) OR ([FirstName] IS NULL AND @original_FirstName IS NULL)) AND (([LastName] = @original_LastName) OR ([LastName] IS NULL AND @original_LastName IS NULL)) AND (([TeamId] = @original_TeamId) OR ([TeamId] IS NULL AND @original_TeamId IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Members] ([FirstName], [LastName], [TeamId]) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @TeamId)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT Members.FirstName, Members.LastName, Team.TeamName FROM Members INNER JOIN Team ON Members.TeamId = Team.TeamId" UpdateCommand="updateTeamMembers" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_MemberId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TeamId" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TeamId" Type="Int64" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="TeamId" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TeamName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="217px" Width="596px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TeamName" HeaderText="Team Name" SortExpression="TeamName" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
```

Update command when I configure through datasource (Doesn't update):

```
UPDATE [Members] SET [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [TeamId] = @TeamId WHERE [MemberId] = @original_MemberId AND (([FirstName] = @original_FirstName) OR ([FirstName] IS NULL AND @original_FirstName IS NULL)) AND (([LastName] = @original_LastName) OR ([LastName] IS NULL AND @original_LastName IS NULL)) AND (([TeamId] = @original_TeamId) OR ([TeamId] IS NULL AND @original_TeamId IS NULL))
```

Comment: Any update? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I added  original_TeamId , original_FirstName , original_LastName , original_TeamName but then got the error:" Procedure or function 'updateTeamMembers' expects parameter 'original_TeamId', which was not supplied." I tried finding a tutorial online so i could just follow that step by step but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the stored procedure, you specify the arguments comma separated, something like this:

```
EXEC updateTeamMembers @ParamValue1, @ParamValue2, @ParamValue3, @ParamValue4, @ParamValue5...
```

First of all, it's a good practice to specify the arguments as key value pair, where the key is the stored procedure parameter name and the value is the value you want to pass to that parameter. So, the above query will look like this:

```
EXEC updateTeamMembers
   @TeamId = @ParamValue1,
   @FirstName = @ParamValue2,
   @LastName = @ParamValue3,
   @TeamName = @ParamValue4
```

If you do this, will observe that you don't have a fifth parameter.

To help you more, you should paste the code from VS.

Comment: Hi Nițu, thanks for your response, I've now added my HTML. I understand what you are saying but I don't ever EXEC my procedure, just click stored procedure when I configure the datasource.

Comment: I think that when the stored procedure is called by asp.net, it's called with the original parameters too ie besides the four parameters you already declared (TeamId, FirstName, LastName, TeamName), the framework passes the parameters original_TeamId, original_FirstName, original_LastName and original_TeamName. Try to add these 4 to the stored procedure definition. This is just a hunch.